# logging.level.root does not work (spring Boot)

Tags: java, logging, spring-boot, logback

I have property `logging.level.root=FATAL` in my application.properties, but it does not work. Application stil uses levels defined in my `logback-spring.xml`

I have read whole http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-logging but I am unable to find a clue what could be wrong.

My `logback-spring.xml` starts with

```
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
```

Then standard logger configuration, like

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="INFO"/>
```

Where is the code that uses `logging.level.*` property? I have checked `org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem, org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackConfigurator, org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem` but I am unable to find any references to `logging.level.*` properties.

I have same issue with Spring Boot 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.1 but it does not work in any of them.

Comment: `logging.level.root` will only affect the level for a logger that doesn't have more specific configuration. In other words, the configuration of a logger named `org.hibernate` will override the configuration of the root logger for any logging done by a logger named `org.hibernate.*`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`logging.level.root` property works fine unless there is more specific logger configuration elsewhere. In my case, I had a lot of package/class-specific configuration in my xml configuration file.

I decided to remove all this package/class-specific entries from xml config file (that file resides inside jar file). Now I have complete flexibility configuring log levels from environment variables.